# ECG Shield electronic circuit explanation

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, biopotential

I have this electronic circuit which is from a shield for the Arduino which allows me to collect ECG signals. However I do not understand what is happening. I am familiar with op-amps and amplifiers in general but do not understand this circuit.

There is a [INA321EA](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbos168) (PDF) instrumentation amplifier and a [OPA43040U](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbos073) (PDF), which I can find on the internet, however I would like an explanation of what is happening in the circuit so I can learn how each component works.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXL2A.png

Comment: Is there supposed to be a circuit there?

Comment: @akellyirl  There are supposed to be links to datasheets too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  first op amp sets up a reference at Vcc/2 for single supply operation.  The resistors on the input limit current to the body and set up a body reference at or near the common mode voltage on the electrodes (using big noisy resistors).  The instrumentation amp takes the differential signal, provides a gain of 5, and spits it out as a single-ended output,  where the next op amp low-pass filters it, and then sends it to an inverting amp with a big gain (1M/3.3k) that also removes most of the DC offset prior to amplification.

Comment: Why use the low pass filter here? Also I cannot see the inverting amp.

Comment: Actually I see it, but why the 4.7 nF capacitor (C4).